# F# function to sort Excel "variants" in Excel-Dna

Tags: sorting, f#, excel-dna

When trying to sort a 1d array of variants (here by "variant" I mean all the Excel types, eg bool, double (and date), string, various errors...) with the following function :

```
[<ExcelFunction(Category="test", Description="sort variants.")>]
    let sort_variant ([<ExcelArgument(Description= "Array to sort.")>] arr : obj[]): obj[] =
        arr
        |> Array.sort
```

I get the following error : `Error  FS0001  The type 'obj' does not support the 'comparison' constraint. For example, it does not support the 'System.IComparable' interface`, probably meaning that there is no generic ordering function available on all obj types.

But Excel has a natural ordering function, which I'd like to emulate (at least ballpark). Eg double (and dates) < string < bool < error...

**My question** : What is the idiomatic way to sort an array of "variants" in F# / Excel-Dna? (I am after a function which takes an `obj[]` and return an `obj[]`, nothing else, not a macro...)

My (temporary?) solution : 
I created a “discriminated union” type

```
type XLVariant = D of double | S of string | B of bool | NIL of string
```

(not really sure whether NIL is necessary but it did not hurt. Also in my real life code I added a `DT of DateTime` instance as I need to distinguish dates from doubles).

```
let toXLVariant (x : obj) : XLVariant =
    match x with
    | :? double as d -> D d
    | :? string as s -> S s
    | :? bool   as b -> B b
    | _              -> NIL "unknown match"

let ofXLVariant (x : XLVariant) : obj =
    match x with
    | D d   -> box d
    | S s   -> box s
    | B b   -> box b
    | NIL _ -> box ExcelError.ExcelErrorRef

[<ExcelFunction(Category="test", Description="sort variants.")>]
let sort_variant ([<ExcelArgument(Description= "Array to sort.")>] arr : obj[]): obj[] =
    arr
    |> Array.map toXLVariant
    |> Array.sort
    |> Array.map ofXLVariant
```

(for the sake of simplicity, I missed the Errors types, but the idea is the same)

Comment: I don't know Excel-Dna well enough to write a proper answer, but your DU solution looks like a good one to me: by ordering the DU cases to match Excel's natural ordering function (which I didn't know about), you're getting a lot of benefit for not that much code. I'd say that what you've written is a good approach, and I can't think of a way to improve it.

Comment: Since the type information is already part of the `obj` value, maybe it's simpler if you just implement `IComparer<obj>` with the desired ordering made explicit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems a bit more explicit to me, since it just sticks to the CLR type system:

```
// Compare objects in the way Excel would
let xlCompare (v1 : obj) (v2 : obj) =
    match (v1, v2) with
    | (:? double as d1), (:? double as d2) -> d1.CompareTo(d2)
    | (:? double), _ -> -1
    | _, (:? double) -> 1
    | (:? string as s1), (:? string as s2) -> s1.CompareTo(s2)
    | (:? string), _ -> -1
    | _, (:? string) -> 1
    | (:? bool as b1), (:? bool as b2) -> b1.CompareTo(b2)
    | (:? bool), _ -> -1
    | _, (:? bool) -> 1
    | _              -> 2

[<ExcelFunction(Category="test", Description="sort variants.")>]
let sort_variant ([<ExcelArgument(Description= "Array to sort.")>] arr : obj[]): obj[] =
    Array.sortWith xlCompare arr
```